# Why is the internal component render completely if set via markup? Is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I faced one incomprehensible behavior of component rendering. In my example, there is a DataTable component, in it you can edit the contents of each table cell, below is a piece of code (see the full example at https://github.com/Cfon/react-render-bug). So, if you call the internal component Table, as a function in the markup, then if you change the data in the cell, then React updates the current edited cell. But if you call the component as a tag in the markup and try to edit the data, then the whole table is updated! 
Either I don’t understand something or this is a bug of React.

```js
export const DataTable = props => {
    const [_data, setData] = useState(props.initialData);    
    const [_edit, setEdit] = useState({row: null, cell: null});

    const handleShowEditor = event => {
        setEdit({
            row: parseInt(event.target.dataset.row),
            cell: event.target.cellIndex,
        });
    };

    const updateCell = value => {
        const { row, cell } = _edit;
        const dataCopy = [..._data];
        dataCopy[row][cell] = value;
        setData(dataCopy);
        setEdit({row: null, cell: null});
    };

    const { headers } = props;
    const Table = () => {
        return (
            <table className="table table-dark">
                <thead onClick={handleSort}>
                    <tr>
                        ....
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody onDoubleClick={handleShowEditor}>
                    {_data.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                        <tr key={rowIndex}>
                            {row.map((cell, cellIndex) => {
                                return (
                                    <td key={cellIndex} data-row={rowIndex}>
                                        {_edit.row === rowIndex &&
                                        _edit.cell === cellIndex ? (
                                            <Editor
                                                cell={cell}
                                                update={updateCell}
                                            />
                                        ) : (
                                            cell
                                        )}
                                    </td>
                                );
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div>            
            <Table />                      
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question.
In short, in the case of the form of the `<Table />` tag, react-dom creates a react element that is completely rendered, since the state of the external DataTable component changes, and the Table component has no state.
In the case of expressing a function call {Table ()}, react element is not created, but internal react elements representing the Table component are returned and they become part of the DataTable component, and when the state changes, the react-dom can determine parts of the component that require rerendering.